# .NET ListView footer controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

New to using the ListView control and I'm trying to retrieve the value of some textboxes in the layout template.  Here's my aspx code:

```
<asp:ListView
ID="lvFundingSummary" 
OnItemCommand="lvFundingSummary_onItemCommand"
OnItemDataBound="lvFundingSummary_ItemDataBound"
runat="server" >                       
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table 
            id="Table1" 
            runat="server" 
            style="background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-color: #999999;
            border-style:none;
            border-width:1px;">
            <tr>
                <td>No data was returned.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate> 

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%; text-align:left; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblResearchArea" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PlName")%>' />&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="width: 30%; text-align:right; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblFundingGross" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FundingGross", "{0:c}")%>' />&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%; text-align:right; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblGross" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AllGross", "{0:c}")%>' />&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="Table2" style="width: 90%" runat="server">
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                <td id="Td1" runat="server" width="100%">

                    <table 
                        ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" 
                        runat="server" 
                        style="width: 98%">
                        <tr id="TrHeading"  runat="server">
                            <th id="Th1" style="width: 50%; text-align:left;" runat="server">
                                Research Area</th>
                            <th id="Th2" style="width: 30%; text-align:right;" runat="server">
                                Gross</th>
                            <th id="Th3" style="width: 20%; text-align:right;" runat="server">
                                All Gross</th>
                        </tr>                       
                    </table>

                    <div style="overflow-y:scroll; height:400px;">
                        <table style="border: 10px; width: 100%">
                            <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
                        </table>                            
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
                <td id="Td2" runat="server" 
                    style="text-align: center;background-color: #5D7B9D;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #FFFFFF">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="TrFooter" runat="server">
                <td style="width: 50%; text-align:left;">
                    <b>Total(s)</b>
                </td>
                <td id="TdTotal" style="width: 30%; text-align:right;">
                    <b>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalFunding" runat="server" /></b>
                </td>
                <td id="TdTotal" style="width: 20%; text-align:left;">
                    <b>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalGross" runat="server" /></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>          
</asp:ListView>
```

in the lvFundingSummary_PreRender event, I'm trying to access the control as such:

```
Label lbTotFund = this.lvFundingSummary.FindControl("TrFooter").FindControl("lblTotalFunding") as Label
```

but that's not working.  I know this should be a snap, just can't quite seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477549/asp-net-listview-show-computed-summary-in-footer), use

`var lbTotFund = lvFundingSummary.FindControl("lblTotalFunding") as Label;`

in lvFundingSummary_LayoutCreated event, it should do the work

Comment: Thank you sir!  Worked like a charm.